# Install PJSIP in iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, pjsip

I'm trying to install pjsip on the iPhone simulator, but I have un into problems. I followed the tutorial from http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone , and did the following steps:

```
pjproject-2.0.1 $ export DEVPATH=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer

pjproject-2.0.1 $ export CC=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0

pjproject-2.0.1 $ ./configure-iphone configure-iphone error: directory /Developer/Platforms
```

/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer does not exist. Please install iPhone development kit

What am I missing here. Could someone please give me some clues as to how to proceed in resolving this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the latest SDK then the paths are incorrect because the latest Xcode and iOS SDK has the Developer folder within the Xcode app folder. (`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/`)

Change your exports to the following

```
export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
export CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
```

Comment: Thank you Suhail. This is the right answer. I didn't use it as it is. The CC part, I gave the complete path for the gcc. The library is now up and running in the the simulator. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the above link and trying to install the pjsip on iPhone Simulator then skip the **Building PJSIP** instruction section($ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir$ ./configure-iphone$ make dep && make clean && make) go Direct to **Simulator** building instruction hope it can help you. Try and let me know if you are facing any prob.

Comment: Laxman, thanks for the reply. I did follow the follow the steps to the  simulator and only then stumbled upon the above error.
I have got it figured out now. I'll add the answer for others benefit.

Answer (score 0):

[try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848333/just-info-how-to-build-and-compile-pjsip-for-xcode-using-sample-code-ipjsua-t), i just test it using my xcode. And i also test on device. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link. You will get source code from there and can biuld for both device and simulator.

https://github.com/radif/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles